# Android onTouch multi-touch not receiving all touch events

Tags: android, surfaceview, multi-touch

I am using an Android `SurfaceView` and listening for multi-touch events. I am able to detect multiple touches but it seems that the `ACTION_POINTER_UP` touch event is not getting fired. Here is a quick snip of my code.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.i("pointer count", Integer.toString(motionEvent.getPointerCount()));
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I put 2 fingers on the screen the pointer count log out is 2. If I remove one of my fingers the pointer count log out is not 1 and stays at 2. It only goes to 1 if I move my finger that is still on the screen. Why is this and how to I firkin fix it? thanks!

**EDIT**

This problem occurs on my One Plus One and my friends Samsung Galaxy Note 2. It is interesting that when I put it on my Samsung Galaxy s4 the problem did not occur.

Comment: This even will happend only when a non-primary pointer has gone up.

Comment: @SimonMarquis if that is a question. yes!

Comment: No, it wasn't. But if you correctly receive MOVE events, you must do something wrong. A little bit of your code will maybe help to spot the mistake

Comment: Add which action is happening in your log statement, maybe that'll help you (`actionToString(action)`). `getActionIndex` will also tell you which pointer the action is for. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: Thanks @Arve I have done that and it logs out `ACTION_POINTER_UP(1)` although if I do a log after with `action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP` it returns `false`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP` as the action will also contain the pointer index.

`getActionMasked()` will strip out this information, and could be used for comparison.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionMasked()